# Compiled regex lifetime in .Net

Tags: .net, regex, lifetime

I have a Validator class for validating the correctness of a numeric input. When creating class objects, I pass precision and scale to the constructor.
In the method of this class, I use a Regex.
The pattern itself will always be the same for any object.
I want to use the Regex in the most optimal way.

If I use it this way `new Regex (pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)` in Validate method
will it compile every time the method is called? Will it compile every time a class object is created?

Is it worth creating an expression in a static constructor of a class with the goal of compiling it once and using it for all objects?

The documentation says

> You should use compiled regular expressions when you call regular
> expression methods with a specific regular expression relatively
> frequently.

The Validate method will be called frequently. So I think that Regex.Match (pattern, ...) doesn't suit me.

```
public class NumberValidator
{        
    private readonly bool onlyPositive;
    private readonly int precision;
    private readonly int scale;
   
    public NumberValidator(int precision, int scale = 0, bool onlyPositive = false)
    {
        this.precision = precision;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.onlyPositive = onlyPositive;
        if (precision <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (scale < 0 || scale >= precision)
            ...            
    }

    public bool IsValidNumber(string value)
    {    
        var numberRegex = new Regex(@"^([+-]?)(\d+)([.,](\d+))?$", RegexOptions.Compiled);                  
        var match = numberRegex.Match(value);
            ...
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class NumberValidator
{   
    private static readonly Regex numberRegex;     
    private readonly bool onlyPositive;
    private readonly int precision;
    private readonly int scale;
    
    static NumberValidator()
    {
        numberRegex = new Regex(@"^([+-]?)(\d+)([.,](\d+))?$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }     

    public NumberValidator(int precision, int scale = 0, bool onlyPositive = false)
    {
        this.precision = precision;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.onlyPositive = onlyPositive;
        if (precision <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (scale < 0 || scale >= precision)
            ...            
    }

    public bool IsValidNumber(string value)
    {                             
        var match = numberRegex.Match(value);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex compilation is an expensive operation, so you want to do it once and reuse the compiled instance, i.e. your 2nd snippet. You certainly do not want to be creating a new compiled Regex instance every time your `IsValidNumber` method is called, which would likely be far slower than using a non-compiled regex due to the overheads of compilation on every call.